# How to make Nodejs connect to Metamask account?

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, metamask

I have a backend write with Nodejs that can connect to contracts and perform functions in those contracts but the problem is I want my Metamask can pass only the account address to the backend. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

there are some third party packages like **node-metamask** 
you can use them

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

add this code snippet in your **views** (hbs template engine) / **HTML** file.

When you load this page, the script will execute and it will get the metamask wallet address if it's installed.

```
<script>
        async function connect() 
        {
            if (window.ethereum) {
                await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
                window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                const account = web3.eth.accounts;
                const walletAddress = account.givenProvider.selectedAddress;
                console.log(`Wallet: ${walletAddress}`);
                window.location.href = `/setup?wallet=${walletAddress}`;
            } 
            else {
                alert("MetaMask is not installed");
            }
        }
</script>
```

after that, It will send the wallet address at a specific backend route to the express.
hence, you can perform actions in node JS with the integration of web3.

```
app.get('/setup', (req, res) => {

    const address = req.query.wallet
    app.locals.address = address

    console.log(app.locals.address)

})
```

here's complete code example: https://github.com/billypentester/web3-dapp